# How to serve this file with these HTTP headers?

Tags: php

I am using a shared hosting, so I can't edit Apache settings.
I need to allow users to download a .crx file in this way:

```
1) The file has the content type application/x-chrome-extension
2) The file is not served with the HTTP header X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
3) The file is served with one of the following content types:
- empty string
- "text/plain"
- "application/octet-stream"
- "unknown/unknown"
- "application/unknown"
```

How can I do this in PHP or in others way ?

Comment: using `getallheaders` you can get a list of all of the current request headers, meaning you can find and match both the `content-type` and `x-content-type-options` to make sure it's a valid incoming request, and as @bsdnoobz has said, you can then use `header` to set the content-type when returning a response.

Comment: but I can insert the header function in a PHP file, not in a .crx file. no ?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html#header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/x-chrome-extension; charset=UTF-8");   // use here both proper settings for your case
//  header("Content-Length: " .filesize($your_crx_file));    // this is realy optional, I do recomend to not include this sentence
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="TheNameThatYouWant.crx"');    // this set the name of the downloaded file on browser side.
readfile($your_crx_file)
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

**Update:**

Sorry I forgot that the file is .crx :)

If your file is `cool_app.crx`, write a wrapper, say `cool_app.php`:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/x-chrome-extension');
include 'cool_app.crx';
```

Then point your link to `cool_app.php`.

Comment: How can the server send these headers when users download the file ?

Comment: @xRobot You need to proxy the download through a PHP script. So instead of giving users that absolute URL of the file, you give them `http://www.mysite.com/download.php?file=file.crx`. Note also that your statement `I am using a shared hosting, so I can't edit Apache settings` is probably not true, you can probably use a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line:

```
AddType application/x-chrome-extension crx
```

to your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments:

```
header('content-type: text/plain'); // set the content-type
readfile('path-to-crx.crx');
```

You first set the content type using the `header` function.

Then, if the file exists on your server, use the `readfile` method to send the file, or if it's generated during execution, just echo the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

this work fine

```
<?php
$file = 'extension.crx';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-chrome-extension');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```